# Javascript show how many elements in root XML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I need this html/javascript file to display HOW MANY elements an XML document has directly under the root element.

This should be showing as:

```
The root element has this many direct children: 2
```

Instead, it it showing as:

```
The root element has this many direct children: 0The root element has this many direct children: 1
```

How do I go about this?

This is the code I am using:

```
 <html land="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadXMLDoc(XML65) {
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open("GET", XML65, false);
                xhttp.send();
                return xhttp.responseXML;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing XML FILE</h1>
        <script>
            var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("XML65.xml");

            for (i = 0; i < xmlDoc.childNodes.length; i++)
            {
                thisNode = xmlDoc.childNodes[i];
                document.write("The root element has this many direct children: " + i);

            }
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: is this doing something "wrong"?

Comment: Its not showing me the total amount of children under root.  "The root element has this many direct children: 0The root element has this many direct children: 1 " is how it shows instead of a total number (which is actually 2)   It should show as:   The root element has this many direct children: 2

Comment: so, `xmlDoc.childNodes.length` would be the right answer, no need to loop at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script should be

```
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("XML65.xml");
document.write("The root element has this many direct children: " + xmlDoc.childNodes.length);
```

P.S. I would highly recommend familiarising yourself with alternatives to `document.write`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: @CodedMe: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.